# WSO2 WSF PHP - WSClientProxy->__call not returning big response

Tags: php, wso2, wsh

I've been trying to consume a service using WSClient in WSDL mode, but the response is always a array with an empty string.

I'm using WSO2 WSF for PHP(WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP) and my PHP version is 5.3.

I think the problem could be the size of the response(I know its big). There is a way to define maxReceivedMessageSize and maxStringContentLength?

What should I do? There is a "WSO2 WSF for PHP" alternative library?

**Code:**

```
function getCatalog($options, $input)
{   
        $client = new WSClient($options);

        // get proxy object reference form client
        $proxy = $client->getProxy();

        //return $proxy->BuscaCatalogo($input);
        var_dump($proxy->BuscaCatalogo($input));
}
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  ["BuscaCatalogoResult"]=>  string(0) ""
}
```

**Log Message:**
[Thu Dec 13 11:00:59 2012] [error] soap_builder.c(329) Error occurred when building node

-- SOLVED
This topic is little old, but here is an alternative for WSO2, https://code.google.com/p/wse-php/source/browse/examples/soap-wsa-example.php?r=407b920367574e85f1302a76ec5a2991b746d79c.

**OBS: I'm a PHP developer**

Comment: I suppose the value inside "BuscaCatalogoResult" is supposed to be xml, have you tried looking into either the source code or add <pre></pre> tags before the var dump if you are doing that in an html page just to make sure the content is really empty? I realize now this is  a 1 year and a half old :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009115/php-which-soap-lib-to-use