# PHP which SOAP lib to use?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I just commented a question related to the SOAP extension, and I tried to find any alternative, but there isn't any:

- SOAP extension - [not supported since 2010](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&package_name%5b%5d=SOAP+related)
- nuSOAP - [not supported since 2010](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/?source=navbar)
- WSO2 - [not supported since 2010](https://github.com/wso2/wsf/tree/master/php)

Do you know of any supported SOAP lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there are currently 2 supported PHP SOAP libs:

- BeSimple SOAP which is a Symfony boundle - [supported](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoap)
  *But [it extends SOAP
  extension](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoap/blob/master/src/BeSimple/SoapClient/SoapClient.php),
  which is not supported since 2010 and [has currently about 150
  reported and unfixed bugs](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&package_name%5b%5d=SOAP+related) (probably impossible to workaround some of
  them, but who knows).*
- Zend 2 SOAP - [supported](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Soap)
  *I think this is the best choice currently, because the developers have control over its dependencies.*