# Read soap:Body from soap response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, response

I have a soap response with this structure in PHP:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:srv="http://srv.soap.factura.sit.mx.com">
<soap:Body>
<srv:responseXMLT>
<return>&lt;tfd:ValorXML version="1.0" Key="000XY 212XH" FechaResponse="2014-05-14T14:37:45"/>
</return>
</srv:timbraCFDIXMLTestResponse>
```

I want to read the data inside of return and save each value in a database, but how can I read the value of .??

Thanks for all!!

Comment: You should use a SOAP client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009115/php-which-soap-lib-to-use
Or parse the xml manually with for example SimpleXML.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I use SOAP client and the xml that I showed is the response with the SOAP client (i have user, password, etc.)
But don't know how to extract the information.

Comment: Usually the client parses the answer and returns it as for example a php array or stdClass instances or other class instances if there is a mapping. So I don't think you need to parse the XML. But ofc this depends on what client you use...

Comment: I use SOAP extension, and get the info with __getLastResponse() and I tried save the response in database. How can I parse the XML?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php
Why do you use the `__getLastResponse()` ? it is mainly for debugging I think... The client parses the WSDL, so you can use the operation name described in there, and building the xml and parsing it will go automatical (mostly). I don't recommend you the SOAP extension, because it is not supported since 2010, and has about 150 unsolved issues, so you will certainly run into some bugs.